# Imagick extension shows on phpinfo but shows error unable to load dynamic library when running simple php command in command prompt

Tags: php, windows, apache, imagick

Successfully install imagick into my system and able to loaded imagick extentsion (appears in phpinfo) but when running simple php command, such as `php -v` in my command prompt, it shows error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '[MY_SERVER_PATH]\PHP\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

My system info as follows:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64Bit
- PHP: 5.6.19
- ImageMagick: ImageMagick-6.9.4-10-Q16-x64-dll
- PHP Imagick: php_imagick-3.3.0-5.6-ts-vc11-x64

[My Error screenshot...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgJYT.jpg)
I run 
    print_r( get_loaded_extensions() );
and the result is:

> Array ( [0] => Core [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgJYT.jpg) => bcmath [2] => calendar [3] => ctype [4] => date [5] => ereg [6] => filter [7] => ftp [8] => hash [9] => iconv [10] => json [11] => mcrypt [12] => SPL [13] => odbc [14] => pcre [15] => Reflection [16] => session [17] => standard [18] => mysqlnd [19] => tokenizer [20] => zip [21] => zlib [22] => libxml [23] => dom [24] => PDO [25] => openssl [26] => SimpleXML [27] => wddx [28] => xml [29] => xmlreader [30] => xmlwriter [31] => apache2handler [32] => curl [33] => fileinfo [34] => gd [35] => intl [36] => imap [37] => mbstring [38] => mysql [39] => mysqli [40] => Phar [41] => pdo_mysql [42] => soap [43] => xmlrpc [44] => imagick [45] => mhash )

I just dont understand why php command prompt always shows error.

P.S: I am not using any XAMPP or WAMPP packages...

**update:**

I wonder what extension that CLI loaded so i run a simple php script and this is the result:

> D:>php -r "print_r( get_loaded_extensions() );"

`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\Eric\web\PHP\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module coul
d not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => bcmath
    [2] => calendar
    [3] => ctype
    [4] => date
    [5] => ereg
    [6] => filter
    [7] => ftp
    [8] => hash
    [9] => iconv
    [10] => json
    [11] => mcrypt
    [12] => SPL
    [13] => odbc
    [14] => pcre
    [15] => Reflection
    [16] => session
    [17] => standard
    [18] => mysqlnd
    [19] => tokenizer
    [20] => zip
    [21] => zlib
    [22] => libxml
    [23] => dom
    [24] => PDO
    [25] => openssl
    [26] => SimpleXML
    [27] => wddx
    [28] => xml
    [29] => xmlreader
    [30] => xmlwriter
    [31] => curl
    [32] => fileinfo
    [33] => gd
    [34] => intl
    [35] => imap
    [36] => mbstring
    [37] => mysql
    [38] => mysqli
    [39] => Phar
    [40] => pdo_mysql
    [41] => soap
    [42] => xmlrpc
    [43] => mhash
)`

Comment: Most likely the CLI and the http module version of php use different `php.ini` configuration files.

Comment: @arkascha I already make sure I edit the correct php.ini file that http module loaded. I am not sure if CLI has another version of php.ini since the result after running `php --ini` is:     `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         D:\Eric\web\PHP\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)` <br/> I will try to search if CLI module uses another `php.ini` file